# Trying to populate mongoose schemas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This issue seems to be common but the answers for it vary. I am trying to populate these two models with their data.

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const app = express();

app.listen(4000,()=>{
    console.log('server listening on port 4000')
});


mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/testDB',{useNewUrlParser:true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useCreateIndex: true, useFindAndModify:true });

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
})

const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    content: String,
    author: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User',
    }
  })

const Post = mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

const user = new User({
    username: 'alex antoine',
})

const posts = new Post({
    content: 'I hope this works'
})

UserSchema.virtual('Post',{
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: 'author',
    ref:'Post',
})

const populateUser = async(username)=>{

    const user = await User.findOne({username}).populate('posts');

    const userPopulated = await user.populate('Post').execPopulate();

    console.log(userPopulated);
}

const save = async()=>{

    user.save();
    posts.save();
}

save();

populateUser('alex antoine');
```

The response I received from this is

```
Populated User {
  posts: [],
  _id: 60dbe989fd1ab074d0ab0541,
  username: 'alex antoine',
  __v: 0
}
```

This seems to be a common issue that a lot of people had but none of their answers seems to work for me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You're not declaring your user's posts as a virtual field right. Your PostSchema is correct, but your UserSchema should look like this:

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: String
})

UserSchema.virtual('posts', {
  ref: Posts,
  localfield: '_id',
  foreignField: 'author'
});
```

This way, when dealing with a user document, you can populate its posts:

```
user.populate('posts').execPopulate();
```

Comment: I've tried that and I still not seeing the contents from post inside the user collection. The response I'm getting now is this: { _id: 60dcc22f0a75167f21ea9e86, username: 'alex antoine', __v: 0 }.

Comment: Maybe try defining your models AFTER you define the virtual field in the UserSchema. The way your code is presented it looks like you add the virtual field to the schema after you define the User model.

Answer (score 0):

result User.findOne({username}).populate('posts').exec();

// At the exec() try using `execPopulate()`

Then at the `ref` add the required: true` option